# Check if subprocess currently running in any thread using Python

Tags: python, timer, subprocess, python-multithreading

I am using the threading.Timer function to run many timers at once. Once each timer ends, the function called uses subprocess with the "say" command, as shown below:

```
subprocess.call(["say", "hello world"])
```

Sometimes the timers go off shortly after each other and then they start talking over each other. How can I get them to wait for each other so that they do not overlap?

I still want to be able to do other things in the main program while this is happening (such as making new timers) so I don't think I can just use popen.wait() or .join()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `say` executable runs quickly, you can just lock its invocation:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def your_thread_function():
    do_something_slow()
    with lock:
        subprocess.call(["say", "hello world"])
```

If the `say` executable itself is slow, you will have to store its output and only print it out (again, with locking) at the end of the invocation:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def your_thread_function():
    # You can also use subprocess.check_output.
    p = subprocess.Popen(["say", "hello world"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    with lock:
        print(out)
```

Comment: The first example worked perfectly for my application, thanks!

Comment: @bbqed: in general, it is good idea to protect `subprocess.Popen()` with a lock too (it is unrelated to the question but it avoids various issues with multithreading and subprocesses (e.g., race conditions due to platform bugs)). `Popen()` returns immediately without waiting for the child process to finish; therefore it is ok to protect it with a lock here.